# Using TeamCity to build local project in order to test setings

Tags: teamcity

I want to experiment with my project output on the TeamCity. I dont want to use git or any other version control system.

Is there a way to turn off the VCS in teamcity and make it build and execute local projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just install TeamCity on your machine, up to 20 build configurations it's free. VCS roots are completely optional, you can just build solutions from a local path - VCS roots are just a means to *getting* your code locally from a repo so you can build / interact with it.

Comment: is correct, when you get to the step to configure the VCS root you can simple just Skip over it and then on your build steps set their working directories to be your local project location.